# Fetch certain rows from MySQL recordset

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Below is a code snippet which works fine using MySQL connector 6.6.5

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("uspSelectsitemap", MySqlConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("SiteMap");
da.Fill(dt);

DataRow[] dtrows = dt.Select("ParentID IS NULL");
foreach (DataRow dr in dtrows)....
```

Unfortunately I found out my web host still uses MySQL 5.0 and I cannot use **da.Fill(dt);** and **dt.Select("ParentID IS NULL");** so I must make adjustments.  As you can see from the above I have returned rows and then I fetch certain rows from that datatable and iterate through those rows.  This will not work with MySQL 5.0 and I want to know if there anyway to do this in MySQL 5.0 such as with a dataset?

Comment: you mean the mysql connector for v6.6.5, right? The DB itself is still in the v5.6.x series.

Comment: Yes, I was using the 6.6.5 connector which, once I moved everything to the web host I found didn't work so now I have to use the 5.5.15 connector.  Bare in mind this my first time doing some of this so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Just being cautious. if you say "mysql 6.6.5", we're going to think you're actually running v6.6.5 of the mysql **server**. In which case, can we borrow your time machine?